# RUN composer install and npm install in every build of a container

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, composer-php

I'm trying to create a php-apache container with npm and composer installed and run `composer install`, `npm install` in every build, but I'm getting errors.

```
# Dockerfile

FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        npm \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Enable apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

EXPOSE 80
#RUN composer install
#RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3"

services:
  painel-admin:
    build:
      context: ./bin/painel-admin
    container_name: 'painel-admin'
    command: >
      sh -c "php /usr/local/bin/composer install"
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "81:80"
      - "82:443"
    volumes:
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-..}:/var/www/html
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./config/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LOG_DIR-./logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2
```

log error:

> Action '-D FOREGROUND sh -c php /usr/local/bin/composer install' failed.

Same error if I try with `npm install`.

I can run the commands inside the docker, but I want to automate that

Comment: It'd be best if you `RUN npm install` in your Dockerfile like you show.  That would mean `COPY`ing your application code into the image, and not bind-mounting it in `volumes:`.  Changing `ENTRYPOINT` in the image to `CMD` will also make the `command:` override work, but it changes the container to run a build-time command instead of the HTTP daemon.

Comment: What have you tried to check for the cause of that error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are following you an incorrect approach. Those commands are part of the image building process, so they should be part of your Dockerfile.

And build process happens **before** volumes are available (the container is not running, so it's not possible to depend on those). What you need to do is copy the necessary files to the image you are building before you run `composer install`.

A more sensible approach, taking advantage of [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) dockerfiles would be:

```docker
## First stage. Copy project files and run composer
FROM composer:2 as composer_stage

RUN rm -rf /var/www && mkdir -p /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY composer.json composer.lock symfony.lock .env ./
COPY public public/

RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --prefer-dist --no-scripts --no-progress --no-suggest --no-interaction --no-dev --no-autoloader

RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize --apcu --no-dev

COPY bin bin/
COPY config config/
COPY src src/

RUN composer run-script $NODEV post-install-cmd; \
    chmod +x bin/console;

## Second stage. Build NPM dependencies

FROM node:12 as npm_builder

COPY --from=composer_stage /var/www/html /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY yarn.lock package.json webpack.config.js ./
COPY assets ./assets

RUN yarn install
RUN yarn encore prod

# I'm using yarn here, but using npm would be similar, depending on how your project is setup

# RUN npm install
# RUN npm run build # if necessary and the command exists in your project

## Third stage, mostly copied from your original Dockerfile

FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y

COPY --from=npm_builder /var/www/html /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        npm \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Enable apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

This way, your final resulting image does not include any of the development dependencies. The image is thought mostly for production, so you can build it and deploy it.

To run it locally during development, you just run the same image locally with your desired volume mount-points. You would only need to rebuild the image whenever your dependencies change or are upgraded.

You'll  need to adjust the paths so it matches your desired configuration (I'm building the project on `/var/www/html` and I point the webserver to `/var/www/html/public`, but you can easily change those).

Since you are using an image that includes both a webserver and the PHP runtime, that should be it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @yivi. i'm using Laravel. so i should copy vendor and node_modules to avoid installing all packages again in every build?

Comment: No, you copy only the files that I show in the `Dockerfile` above. `composer.json` and `composer.lock`, and then the `package.json` and `package-lock.json`. `vendor` and `node_modules` are created **within** the image, not copied from your machine.

Comment: you said that you pointed the webserver to `/var/www/html/public`. Where do you did that?

Comment: It's not in there. Your webserver configuration is not included in your question either. Wherever you configure your webserver (apache, in your case), you would point to that directory.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to put your composer install in your entrypoint.

I would normally use a file for this. You might want to try this.

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

php /usr/local/bin/composer install

exec "$@"
```

and in your dockerfile

```
# ...

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Which would result in something like this.

```
/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

Since the last line of the entry point is `exec "$@"` it would take all parameters passed to entrypoint.sh and execute it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Julien. But i think i need to run the command in the docker-compose.yml because i need the volume that i pointed in there

Comment: Maybe you should give it a try. The volumes should exist when the entrypoint is used.